# NXT programming?

Tags: nxt

I would like to program some stuff for a LEGO NXT robot. The "API" included with the robot is quite limited, so I went on to find some alternatives. There seems to be a bunch of languages/add-ons/compilers for this task. The thing is that I don't know which one to choose, or even use. I'm on a mac with OS 10.8.

I am good with C#, Objective-C, and can work my way around C/C++ and Python. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd check out [`nxt-python`](https://code.google.com/p/nxt-python/). There are NXT bindings for probably every popular language by now.

Comment: @Blender How do I get it running?

Comment: @Fiire See https://code.google.com/p/nxt-python/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like C, I suggest you try out [Not eXactly C](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nbc), a modified version of C for programming NXT bricks. If you prefer a version more like C, give [RobotC](http://robotc.net) a try. RobotC is commercial software, however.

Getting NXC up and running is as easy as installing the [Bricx Command Center](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net) IDE. NXC works with the standard LEGO firmware, but it also comes with an enhanced version with bug-fixes and enhancements. RobotC provides its own IDE and firmware which you can try a 30 day trial and then purchase a license key from the RobotC website.

If you really like Python, have a look at [nxt-python](https://code.google.com/p/nxt-python/). It's as easy as installing a compatible driver/interface for nxt-python to communicate with the NXT brick, and then installing the [latest release](https://code.google.com/p/nxt-python/downloads/list) of the nxt-python libraries. How to do so is clearly outlines on the [Installation](https://code.google.com/p/nxt-python/wiki/Installation) page.

I suggest you setup BricxCC and nxt-python, and give them a try first. If NXC isn't right for you, you can grab a trial version of RobotC that you can try out for 30 days before purchasing the full version.